# Как сделать процентную вероятность выведения той или иной картинки из 2 массивов?

Tags: javascript, функции, случайные-числа

Есть 2 массива

```
const truePhotos = ['1 фото', '2 фото', '3 фото','4 фото',...'100 фото',]
const funnyPhotos = ['1 фото', '2 фото']
```

Делаю рандомное выведение картинки из первого массива

```
function getPhoto() {
    return truePhotos[Math.floor(Math.random() * truePhotos.length)]
}
```

Теперь хочу реализовать в этой функции 10% шанс выведения кляксы - смешного фото)) То есть когда человек обращается к функции `getPhoto()` он с 10% вероятностью получал фото из массива `funnyPhotos.`

И желательно хотел бы сделать на будущее если будет, например 4 массива, у одного шанс 10% у другого 40% и т.д.

Совершенно не могу подступиться к решению этой идеи

Answer (score 0):

Можно генерировать случайное число `rand_num` от нуля до 9, потом возвращать в соотвествии с вероятностями:

```
let rand_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
if(rand_num == 0)
    return firstarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstarray.length)]
if(rand_num == 1 || rand_num == 2 || rand_num == 3 || rand_num == 4)
    return secondarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondarray.length)];
return truePhotos[Math.floor(Math.random() * truePhotos.length)]
```